# Using objdump on ARM architecture: Disassembling to INTEL arch

Tags: arm, x86-64, intel, disassembly, objdump

I have an object file and am trying to disassemble it. When I use:

`objdump -d example.o`
I get an assembly in code in the file format of elf64-littleaarch64.

I am trying to disassemble this into INTEL elf64-x86-64, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: You can't disassemble ARM binary code to x86-64 assembly. This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Disassembly is just conversion between binary and text representation of machine instructions for a given ISA.  x86-64 is a different instruction-set; machine translation of a program from AArch64 to x86-64 would be called binary recompilation or something like that.  There is no simple procedure; look at how complicated Rosetta-2 is, or emulators like QEMU.

Answer (score 0):

aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump -s -d
I thinks this works but only I use once in a simple example

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).